# Remove outer most curly bracket with Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove the outer most curly bracket while keeping only the inner string. My code almost works 100%, except when

```
expr = 'namespace P {\\na; b;}'

# I expect '\\na; b;'
# but I get 'namespace P {\na; b;}' instead
```

Any idea how to fix my regex string?

```
import doctest
import re

def remove_outer_curly_bracket(expr):
   """
   >>> remove_outer_curly_bracket('P {')
   'P {'
   >>> remove_outer_curly_bracket('P')
   'P'
   >>> remove_outer_curly_bracket('P { a; b(); { c1(d,e); } }')
   ' a; b(); { c1(d,e); } '
   >>> remove_outer_curly_bracket('a { }')
   ' '
   >>> remove_outer_curly_bracket('')
   ''
   >>> remove_outer_curly_bracket('namespace P {\\na; b;}')
   '\\na; b;'
   """

   r = re.findall(r'[.]*\{(.*)\}', expr)
   return r[0] if r else expr

doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: `'namespace P {a; b;}'` returns `'a; b;'` for me. What were you hoping for it to return?

Comment: What's the expected output for `'namespace P {a; b;}'`? `'a; b;'` seems correct to me as it is what's inside the curly brackets.

Comment: @Amadan Ok, but only if the brace at the end of the string or with look-ahead.

Comment: @Amadan GREEDY. Of course. My apologies.

Comment: I apologize due to typo. It failed when I have `'namespace P {\\na; b;}'`. I expect `\\na; b;'` but the regex failed to catch the `{ }` pattern when there is `\\n` in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suffices:

```
def remove_outer_curly_bracket(expr):
    r = re.search(r'{(.*)}', expr, re.DOTALL)
    return r.group(1) if r else expr
```

The match will start as soon as possible, so the first `{` will indeed match the leftmost opening brace. Because `*` is greedy, `.*` will want to be as large as possible, which will ensure `}` will match the last closing brace.

Neither of the braces is a special character, and does not need escaping; also, `[.]*` matches any number of periods in a row, and will not help you at all in this task.

This will not work sensibly if the braces are not balanced; for example, for `"{ { x }"` will return `" { x"`, but fortunately your examples do not include such.

EDIT: That said, this is just prettifying the original a bit. The functionality is unchanged. As blhsing says in comments, it seems your code is doing what it is supposed to. It even passes your tests.

EDIT2: There is nothing special in `'namespace P {\\na; b;}'`. I believe you meant `'namespace P {\na; b;}'`? With a line break inside? Indeed, that would not have worked. I changed my code so it does. The issue is that normally `.` matches every character *except newline*. We can modify that behaviour by supplying the flag `re.DOTALL`.

Comment: Thanks Amadan, I had a typo in my question. My regex failed to detect `{}` when I use `namespace P {\\na; b;}`. I expect the output to be `\\na; b;`.

Comment: Edited in accordance to new info.

Comment: Thanks again Amadan. I learned something new again. `re.DOTALL` is great. I was about to use `r'{(\n?.*)}'`, but `re.DOTALL` is cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: Yes Amadan, I was meant `'namespace P {\na; b;}'` However the Doctest requires `\\` on my end in order to work.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that.